# Need the value of a Google Mobile Ads SDK constant

Tags: ios, admob, cocoapods, nativescript

Can anyone tell me what the ***actual value*** of the `kGADAdLoaderAdTypeUnifiedNative` constant is?

I need to pass it in as the *adType* to the AdLoader but it's not available at runtime. So I want to pass it as a *hardcoded* value.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the value is `6`.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj. Do you mind telling me how you found it. is it documented somewhere, or did you log it out form Xcode etc ..?

Comment: Yes you could log in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

#### It's **6**.

See comments under question.